# MySQL UPDATE query by primary key is sometimes extremely slow

Tags: mysql

A particular UPDATE query on our website sometimes runs extremely slow, and examines a lot more rows than necessary. It filters by the primary key, so I would expect that MySQL would always just need to examine one row.

Here's some examples from MySQL's slow-query log:

```
# Time: 090702 12:59:06
# User@Host: XXX[XXX] @ XXX [XXX]
# Query_time: 21  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 500500
SET timestamp=1246532346;
UPDATE `folders` SET `folder_id` = '1705641', `updated_at` = now() WHERE `folders`.`id` = '1682995';
# Time: 090702 14:13:44
# User@Host: XXX[XXX] @ XXX [XXX]
# Query_time: 17  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 16816745
SET timestamp=1246536824;
UPDATE `folders` SET `folder_id` = '417997', `updated_at` = now() WHERE `folders`.`id` = '1705956';
# Time: 090702 14:15:42
# User@Host: XXX[XXX] @ XXX [XXX]
# Query_time: 13  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 16816719
SET timestamp=1246536942;
UPDATE `folders` SET `folder_id` = '1706267', `updated_at` = now() WHERE `folders`.`id` = '1705956';
# Time: 090702 16:07:43
# User@Host: XXX[XXX] @ XXX [XXX]
# Query_time: 499  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 88668449
SET timestamp=1246543663;
UPDATE `folders` SET `folder_id` = '1707407', `updated_at` = now() WHERE `folders`.`id` = '1706992';
```

The query is run more often than that, though, so it doesn't always expose this behaviour.
Also if I run the same queries manually, they run just fine and return immediately.

I also verified the table and as far as I can see it should be fine:

```
mysql> describe folders;
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                  | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment | 
| user_id          | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                | 
| folder_id        | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                | 
| created_at       | timestamp             | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                | 
| updated_at       | timestamp             | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                | 
| modified_at      | timestamp             | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                | 
| name             | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                | 
| guest_permission | tinyint(3) unsigned   | NO   |     | 1                   |                | 
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from folders;
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| folders |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |      760318 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| folders |          1 | user_id   |            1 | user_id     | A         |       69119 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| folders |          1 | folder_id |            1 | folder_id   | A         |      380159 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another thing is that the MySQL server sometimes locks up and stops accepting connections, and every time this happens I usually find one of these slow queries in the logfile, immediately before the failure. I can't see any relevant error messages in other logfiles, but a MySQL restart makes it responsive again.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on, or what things I could check to narrow the problem down?

EDIT: We're using MySQL 5.0.51a on a dedicated server, and currently 6 webservers running PHP 5.2.6 and connecting via PDO to the MySQL server. All servers are running Debian Lenny. The slow query happens on all webservers.

EDIT: Here's an EXPLAIN for a related query, with and without quotes:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM `folders` WHERE `folders`.`id` = '1682995';
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | folders | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | const |    1 |       | 
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM `folders` WHERE `folders`.`id` = 1682995;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | folders | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | const |    1 |       | 
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That's really interesting, I'd like to know why it does this too. Have you tried EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `folders` WHERE `id` = something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. I forgot that there were some triggers on the `folders` table, and of course it was a query inside one of these triggers which caused my problems...

There's an additional table `tree` which maintains the associations between the folders, and the triggers update these associations when a folder is deleted or moved in the hierarchy. In the `UPDATE` trigger, it has to delete all existing references to the folder, before adding the new references. The relevant `DELETE` query began as follows:

```
DELETE FROM `tree`
  WHERE `folder_id` IN (
    SELECT `folder_id` FROM `children`
  )
  AND ...
```

`children` is a temporary table where I previously store the folder ID's I need.
Now for some reason MySQL can't optimize this query, but if I use a `RIGHT JOIN` instead it works perfectly fine:

```
DELETE `tree`.* FROM `tree`
  RIGHT JOIN children USING (folder_id)
  WHERE ...
```

Since I've changed this query MySQL's slow-query log remains blissfully empty, and we haven't experienced any MySQL lockups.

Answer (score 1):

That is weird, but my guess is it *could* be because your id field is int but you're passing a string (quoted). Try not using a string and see if it helps.

To help figure out exactly what's going on, change the query to a SELECT with the same WHERE clause and run it through EXPLAIN. Like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `folders` WHERE `folders`.`id` = '1682995';
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `folders` WHERE `folders`.`id` = 1682995;
```

See if there is a difference.

[More info on EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html).

Comment: No difference. Also, if that really was the cause I would expect the query to ALWAYS be this slow. But thanks for the help, anyway!